# how to use 'this" inside a singleton object in JavaScript properly?

Tags: javascript, oop, this

```
var a={b:44,c:this.b+1};
```

I want `c` to be `b+1` or 45 in this case. but when I try this, I get `Cannot read property 'b' of undefined` error.

Comment: Cant you set `a = {b:44}` and then add to the map?

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, when creating an object, the execution context doesn't change. Hence, the `this` value is picked up from the top-level in your case. Or to articulate in a different way, you can't access the properties of the object if it's not finished initializing yet.

The actual solution to your problem might be:

```js
var a = { b: 44 };
a.c = a.b + 1;
```

Comment: Does not answer the question. An alternate solution makes sens if you will provide expected one first.

Comment: @ulou Should I change the word "alternate" to something else? Cause now that you say it, it doesn't feel like an alternate solution, but a different way to solve the problem.

Comment: It's not what OP wanted and that's `Or to articulate in a different way, you can't access the properties of the object if it's not finished initializing yet.` not even true. Post is already closed and marked as duplicate.

Comment: @ulou `not even true` Just out of curiosity, I know that the object properties can be accessed inside getters, but how else is my statement false?